# Processing only non-blank lines

Tags: python

I've got the following snippet of code

```
def send(self, queue, fd):
    for line in fd:
        data = line.strip()
        if data:
            queue.write(json.loads(data))
```

Which of course works just fine, but I wonder sometimes if there is a "better" way to write that construct where you only act on non-blank lines.

The challenge is this should use the iterative nature of the for the 'fd' read and be able to handle files in the 100+ MB range.

UPDATE - 
In your haste to get points for this question you're ignoring an import part, which is memory usage.  For instance the expression:

```
 non_blank_lines = (line.strip() for line in fd if line.strip())
```

Is going to buffer the whole file into memory, not to mention performing a strip() action twice.  Which will work for small files, but fails when you've got 100+MB of data (or once in a while a 100GB).

Part of the challenge is the following works, but is soup to read:

```
for line in ifilter(lambda l: l, imap(lambda l: l.strip(), fd)):
    queue.write(json.loads(line))
```

Look for magic folks!

FINAL UPDATE: [PEP-289](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) is very useful for my own better understanding of the difference between [] and () with iterators involved.

Comment: This is not exactly an answer to your question, but for large files, you may want to take a look to buffered IO (http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/sorting-million-32-bit-integers-in-2mb.html)

Comment: I can't really think of a better way.  Only other thing you could do is write your own `__iter__` function for your `fd` object (which you haven't given us much information about) so that it only `yield`s you lines that aren't blank.

Comment: fd is very simple:  ``with open(FILENAME) as fd:``

Comment: "Is going to buffer the whole file into memory". Generator comprehensions will not buffer the whole file in memory, I think you are confused with list comprehensions. The multiple strips could easily be factored out, but were left in for clarity. I've edited my answer to expand upon both topics

Comment: You can rewrite your "soup" sans lambdas as `ifilter(bool, imap(str.strip, fd))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code as written, it's readable and efficient.

An alternative approach would be to write it as a generator comprehension:

```
def send(self, queue, fd):
    non_blank_lines = (line.strip() for line in fd if line.strip())
    for line in non_blank_lines:
        queue.write(json.loads(data))
```

This approach can be beneficial (terser) if you are applying a function that can take an iterator: e.g. python3 print

```
non_blank_lines = (line.strip() for line in fd if line.strip())
print(*non_blank_lines, file='foo')
```

To do away with the multiple calls to strip(), chain together generator comprehensions

```
stripped_lines = (line.strip() for line in fd)
non_blank_lines = (line for line in stripped_lines if line)
```

Note that generator expressions will not adversely affect memory as detailed in this [pep](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

For a more in depth look at this approach, and some performance bench marks, take a look at this set of [notes](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf).

Finally note that rstrip() will outperform strip() if you don't need the full behaviour of strip().

Comment: The PEP you cite is very valuable.

Answer (score 1):

There's simply no "better" way than yours, it works the way it's supposed to, it's easy to read, etc. However, if you do classify speed being "better", small adjustments can be made for sure.

I haven't familiarized myself too much with this speed stuff on Python, but here are few suggestions, which work only under certain conditions. I'm hoping someone else will come up with something better, maybe this answer will help them.

If the file won't contain lines such as

```
       \n
```

but instead only `\n`, then this way will be noticeably faster:

```
def send(self, queue, fd):
    for line in fd:
        if line != '\n':
            queue.write(json.loads(line.strip()))
```

Timeit values:

```
using: strip() :: 1.8722578811916337
using: line != '\n' :: 1.0126976271093881
using: line != '\n' and line != ' \n' :: 1.2862439244170275
```

Notice however, that this might actually get even slower, if the file doesn't have a single line of `\n`, I timed it with fd being `["string", "\n", "test string", "\n", "moreeee", "\n", "An other element"]`

You probably don't know if the lines are `\n` only, however, `.strip()` is quite slow, so there might be more better ways.